# Django ck-editor can't add extra plugin

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, ckeditor

I am trying to add an extra plugin but I can't. When I am inspecting my console it's saying can't load the javascript file. Here is my code:

error which I am getting in my console but I have youtube plugin in my plugins folder:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/plugin.js?t=LAHF”.
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'var/static'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

 CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
        'default': {
            'toolbar': 'full',
            'extraPlugins': ','.join([
                'youtube',
            ]),
    
        },
    }
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    blog_body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True,)
```

I also tried this but didn't work:

```
blog_body = RichTextUploadingField(
        config_name='default',

        # CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins:
        extra_plugins=['youtube'],

        # CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal(...)
        external_plugin_resources=[(
            'youtube',
            'var/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/',
            'plugin.js',
        )],
    )
```